# can't exit prompt after using .help() function in Python 2.7 interactive mode

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and was using the help() function on different String methods in interactive mode.
For example:

```
>>> S = 'abcd'
>>> help(S.isdigit)
```

Output is as expected:

```
Help on built-in function isdigit:

isdigit(...)
    S.isdigit() -> bool

    Return True if all characters in S are digits
    and there is at least one character in S, False otherwise.
(END)
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to exit this prompt no matter what button I press (CTRL+D doesn't work either).
I can close the terminal, but it's obviously cumbersome.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I keep running into this problem on an HPC and can't get out of the help window. Nothing seems to work. I try to just avoid using `help` on HPC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entering `help` in Python's interactive shell invokes [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html).

> When printing output to the console, `pydoc` attempts to paginate the output for easier reading. If the `PAGER` environment variable is set, `pydoc` will use its value as a pagination program.

Unless you've configured it otherwise, pydoc is probably using [`less`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html). In this case press <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit.

---

Note: Lots of programs use `less`-like keybindings. I would add <kbd>Q</kbd> to your list of keyboard commands to try when you can't figure out how to quit a program.